# How do I verify divergence theorem for given vector field and surface?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The vector field is ${\bf{F}}\left( {x,y,z} \right) = x{y^2}{\bf{i}} + y{x^2}{\bf{j}} + e{\bf{k}}$ and the surface $S$ is bounded by $z = \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} $ and $z = 4$.

Comment: To start with, state the **divergence theorem**: $\int\int\int\nabla\cdot \vec{F}dV= \int\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{S}$ where the integral on the left is over the volume and the integral on the right is over the surface of that object.  

Here, $\nabla\cdot F$ is $y^2+ x^2$.  The surface is upper nappe of the cone together with the disk at z= 4 bounded by the circle $x^2+ y^2= 16$.

I would be inclined to use "cylindrical coordinates".

Comment: Good idea. Two hints for the volume integral. The surface in cylindrical coordinates is $z=r$, the integrand is simply $r^2$, for the limits of integration you can consider $z$ driving $r$ and the same $z$ moving from zero to $4$. The surface integral needs a parametrization for the surface to get the vector perpendicular $d{\bf S}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface is in cylindrical coordinates $z=r$, so, $\nabla\cdot{\bf F}=y^2+x^2=r^2$

$$\int_V\nabla\cdot{\bf F}dv=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_0^zr^3drdzd\theta=$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4\dfrac{z^4}{4}dzd\theta=512\pi/5$$

The flux of a vector crossing a surface is surely sometimes important to know, we apply the theorem and with three lines we are done. Now, compare with the direct calculation for the flux. The difference gives a good hint about the importance the theorem has.

The part for the surface of the divergence theorem:

For the cone: As $z=r$, the vector pointing to points in the surface is in cartesian coordinates ${\bf r}=(u\cos v,u\sin v,u)$, $0\leq v\lt2\pi$ and $0\lt u\lt4$. ${\bf} F=(u^3\cos v\sin^2v,u^3\sin v\cos^2v,e)$. For the tangent vectors:

${\bf r}_u=\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial u}=(\cos v,\sin v,1)$

${\bf r}_v=\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial v}=(-u\sin v,u\cos v,0)$

We need the normal vector pointing outward. As ${\bf r}_u$ points to increasing $r$, ${\bf r}_v$ points anticlockwise and they are orthogonal, the normal pointing outward is ${\bf r}_v\times{\bf r}_u$

${\bf r}_v\times{\bf r}_u=(u\cos v,u\sin v,-u)$ and $d{\bf S}=(u\cos v,u\sin v,-u)dudv$

${\bf F}\cdot{\bf r}_v\times{\bf r}_u=2u^4\cos^2v\sin^2v-eu$

$$\int_{S_1}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}=\int_{S_1}{\bf F}\cdot{\bf r}_v\times{\bf r}_ududv=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4(2u^4\cos^2v\sin^2v-eu)dudv$$

For the disk: The vector pointing to points in the surface is ${\bf r}=(u\cos v,u\sin v,4)$, $0\leq v\lt2\pi$ and $0\lt u\lt4$.

${\bf r}_u=\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial u}=(\cos v,\sin v,0)$

${\bf r}_v=\dfrac{\partial {\bf r}}{\partial v}=(-u\sin v,u\cos v,0)$

With a similar reasonig as before, the normal vector pointing outward is

${\bf r}_u\times{\bf r}_v=(0,0,u)$ and $d{\bf S}=(0,0,u)dudv$

${\bf F}\cdot{\bf r}_u\times{\bf r}_v=eu$

$$\int_{S_2}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}=\int_{S_2}{\bf F}\cdot{\bf r}_v\times{\bf r}_ududv=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4eu\;dudv$$

And for the total flux:

$$\int_{S}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}=\int_{S_1}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}+\int_{S_2}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf S}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^42u^4\cos^2v\sin^2v\;dudv=512\pi/5$$

Comment: For the disk: why is $F \cdot r_u \times r_v=e$ instead of $ue$?

Comment: You are right. There were two errors, one balancing the other. Corrected.